# Connect to USB Modem web interface from another PC on network

Tags: networking, usb-modem

So I have a Huawei USB Modem that is plugged into a Windows Server on my network.
I want to be able to access the web interface of the USB Modem from another Windows computer on the network.
The server and computer are connected to a network 192.168.212.x.
The USB Modem is plugged into the server and has IP 192.168.215.1.

On the server this shows as two network interfaces, an ethernet interface and a usb interface.

Is it possible to connect these networks so that I can access the Modem from another computer on the 192.168.212.x network?

The intention is to set up the USB Modem as an SMS gateway, using the http API. WiFi and mobile data are disabled on the USB Modem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows Server where the modem is connected must have also an IP address like `192.168.215.x` assigned to the interface towards the modem. That interface is probably the RNDIS or CDC USB-Ethernet NIC that appears in the system when you connect the modem, and the address is assigned by the DHCP service built into the modem.

There are several approaches that help you solve this.

1. Install a reverse proxy on the server (e.g. Nginx, Caddy). That proxy will listen on server's 192.168.212.x address and it must be configured modem as the upstream. You may also use alternate port to bind the proxy on (e.g. not 80 or 443). The proxy will have very simple configuration, so don't hesitate. This is probably the least intrusive solution.
2. Install RRAS services on the server. Then, you may either configure modem's NIC as outside NAT interface or set up a route in the modem towards the LAN 192.168.212.0/24 via Server's 192.168.215.x address. I prefer to avoid NAT whenever possible.
3. If you can afford changing IP addressing on the LAN or in the modem, you may just try to bridge LAN NIC and modem NIC in the server, so will left with just a single network. But, depending on the modem, that might not work as expected (modem's firmware could be designed so it expects only a single remote MAC address and it already knows that address; bridging will violate that invariant).
4. Consider running your service on the server.

Comment: Thank you, I went with option 1 and setup a Nginx reverse proxy server on the server and can now connect to the modem.